# How to handle an IOException thrown by an HttpClient?

Tags: java, android, rest, ioexception, androidhttpclient

sometimes when trying to call an api from background service of my app, connection is not established and I can see IOException messages(Network error) from my logs.

```
AndroidHttpClient client = null;
        try {
            // Create the end-point client
            client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("TCR Software Android Application");
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 30000); // 10000
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 30000); // 10000

            // Execute the request
            Log.v("RESTClient", "executing " + request.getMethod() + " " + request.getURI());
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            // Get response wrapper
            responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            JSONObject responseWrapper = new JSONObject(responseBody);
            //JSONObject responseWrapper = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

            // Check result type
            if (!responseWrapper.has("ResultType")) throw new RESTClientException(responseWrapper.getString("Message"), Reason.SERVICE_ERROR);

            // Get the data object
            Object responseData = responseWrapper.isNull("Data") ? null : responseWrapper.get("Data");

            // Check for su
            if (responseWrapper.getInt("ResultType") != 1) throw new RESTClientException(responseData == null ? responseWrapper.getString("Message") : responseData.toString(), Reason.APPLICATION_ERROR);

            // Always return JSONArray
            if (responseData == null)
                return new JSONArray();
            if (responseData instanceof JSONObject)
                return new JSONArray().put(responseData);
            else if (responseData instanceof JSONArray)
                return (JSONArray)responseData;
            else if (responseData instanceof Boolean)
                return new JSONArray().put(responseData);
            else if (responseData instanceof Date)
                return new JSONArray().put(responseData);
            else if (responseData instanceof String)
                return new JSONArray().put(responseData);
            else if (responseData instanceof Integer)
                return new JSONArray().put(responseData);
            else
            {
                Log.e("RESTClient", "Unexpected data format returned by server\n" + responseBody);
                throw new RESTClientException("Unexpected data format returned by server. ", Reason.PROTOCOL_ERROR);
            }
        } finally {
            if (client != null) client.close();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("RESTClient", "Unintelligible response from server\n" + responseBody, e);
        throw new RESTClientException("Unintelligible response from server", Reason.PROTOCOL_ERROR, e);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        throw new RESTClientException("Incompatible server protocol", Reason.SERVICE_ERROR, e);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RESTClientException("Failure encoding request data", Reason.INTERNAL_ERROR, e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RESTClientException("Network error", Reason.NO_CONNECTION);
    }
```

I am displaying the Network error message if IOException occurs. But how to fix this issue to not happen. Does increasing setConnectionTimeout, setSoTimeout values to 60 seconds helps to solve this?

Comment: I bet it helps if you log the exception. IOException has a few subclasses so the actual Exception should tell you what is happening.

In general IOException covers many network problems.

Network errors are to be expected so you have to allow for them in production code. In practice you shouldn't see too many during experimenting/developing code or else you could have some network issues between you and the server.

Comment: i can see this exception java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Comment: Your setSoTimeout is currently 30 seconds. If the error only happens sometimes (rather than always) then it means either your network connection to the backend is poor, or the backend is slow to respond. Does increasing to 60000 make the problem happen a lot less often? Or you could time the successful responses and see how long they take.

Comment: it happens only sometimes only to some users. It is very difficult to reproduce on my side. I am assuming if changing to 60000 would solve this issue.

Comment: `catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RESTClientException("Network error", Reason.NO_CONNECTION);`. Terrible. You throw away valuable info and replace it with someting nobody understands. Forward the exception and the info: `catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RESTClientException("IOException", e.getMessage());`.

Comment: ok. I will change this and get back once i get the necessary info.

Comment: It is expected to happen to some users once in a while (think how often you might have a bad network). So you need to handle it in your code (perhaps a retry). But before you do that first you need to double check that it's not caused by something other than a really bad user network. e.g. a slow backend request.

Comment: ok. I changed the catch statement to know exactly what error it is. And also can I change timeout to 60000 ms and send apk to the specific user? keeping 1 minute is ideal?